# Struggling with REST call and certificates

Tags: c#, rest, curl, fiddler, restsharp

I'm trying to talk to a REST web service that requires certificates to make the call. I got two files from my client - a `*.pem` and a `*.key` file.

Using these two files, I can make the call to that web service on the command line using `curl`:

```
curl.exe -k -v "MyUrl" --cert mycert.pem --key mycertkey.key
```

This works. But I would like to use Fiddler and ultimately my own C# code to make that call - but how??

In **Fiddler**, I'm reading about having to provide the certificate as a `ClientCertificate.cer` file in a specific directory..... but I have a `.pem` and a `.key` file - how do those "translate" into a `*.cer` file?

And how can I use those `*.pem` and `*.key` files in my own **C# code** to make a call to that web service (using RestSharp or just a plain `WebRequest`) ?

**Update:** following the answer by Drew Burchett, I imported my `.pem` file into the certificate store on my machine, and then exported it to a `.cer` file ("DER-encoded, binary") and placed it in Fiddler's folder. When attemping a call to the REST service, I still get this error from Fiddler:

> [Fiddler] The connection to '......' failed.
>   System.Security.SecurityException Failed to negotiate HTTPS connection with server.fiddler.network.https; HTTPS handshake to (url) failed.
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException Error with SSPI call, see internal exception; the format of the received message was unexpected or erroneous

Funny enough, the last paragraph (the `System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException` paragraph) shows up in German on my system, while the rest is in English.... odd......

**Update #2:**
Attempting this in C# code using the `WebRequest` with the `https://` prefix and the certificate installed in the certificate store (my own certificates, trusted root certificates) fails with an error:

> System.Net.WebException was caught
>   HResult=-2146233079
>   Message=The request was aborted: no secure SSL/TLS channel could be established.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to translate the .pem file into a .cer file through certificate manager.  In Windows 7, click Start | Run and type in certmgr.msc.  In Windows 8, right-click on the start button and select Run.  Type in certmgr.msc and click OK.  Once you have the certificate manager open:

1. Expand the Personal folder and click on the Certificates folder
2. Right-click on the Certificates folder (or the Personal folder if Certificates does not exist) and click Import.
3. Browse to where your .pem file is saved and select it.
4. Select to import the certificate into the specified folder.

Once the import process is complete, you should see the certificate.  You can then right-click on it and select Export.  Choose the .cer file and provide a path and filename to save the certificate.

If this is a certificate used to identify the server you are connecting (I would suspect that it is) and it is a self-signed certificate, in order to use it in your C# code, you'll need to place it in your Trusted Root Certification Authority folder.  Then, when you call the service using a WebRequest and an https prefix, the certificate will be trusted and the call will succeed.  You can either use the procedure above to import the certificate into the proper folder or you can embed the certificate in your application's "Root" folder using a method found at [Microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4a776e8c-0e10-4f03-908f-7f765d914080/how-to-connect-to-a-http-rest-service-with-self-signed-certificatein-the-server-side?forum=winappswithcsharp):

1. Export the server cert to a .der file
2. Include the cert in your application (I put mine in the Assets Directory)
   Right click on the cert after you include it in your project and
    a. set the Build Action to Content
    b. set the Copy to Output Directory to Copy always
3. Open the package.appxmanifest in the text or XML editor by right clicking on it and add your cert to the "Root"

   ```
     <Extensions>
   <!--Certificates Extension-->
   <Extension Category="windows.certificates">
     <Certificates>
       <Certificate StoreName="Root" Content="Assets\jsanders4.cer" />

     </Certificates>
   </Extension>
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I followed your steps, got a `.cer` file, stored it as `ClientCertificate.cer` in the Fiddler folder - and the error is still the same.... [Fiddler] The connection to '......' failed. System.Security.SecurityException Failed to negotiate HTTPS connection with server.fiddler.network.https; HTTPS handshake to (url) failed. System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException Error with SSPI call, see internal exception; the format of the received message was unexpected or erroneous

Comment: I'm not familiar with using Fiddler, but when I was rolling my own WCF services with certificates and got an SSPI error, it almost always meant that the RSA key either was not associated with the certificate property or did not exist.  A .cer file would not contain an RSA key so that may be the problem.  I would try importing the .pem file into your Trusted Root Certification Authority folder and see if that clears up the problem.

Comment: I tried your tip - unfortunately, it doesn't change anything at all :-( The error in Fiddler is still the same ....

Comment: Is there any way to see the internal exception to which it is referring?  That may provide some clarity.

Comment: I'm sorry - I have **no idea** how to do that in Fiddler :-( .... I get this stuff returned just as a simple text string, and I didn't find any settings or options to tell Fiddler to return that inner exception :-(

Comment: Sorry - maybe stupid question - where or what is the `package.appmanifest` file? I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms - I've never come across such a file....

Comment: It's an XML file that contains configuration information for your application.  You can add it by adding a new object to your project and selcting Application Manifest File as the type.

Comment: Thanks - now I'm getting an error when trying to launch: "The application has failed to start because the configuration is incorrect. Review the manifest file for possible errors" ......

Comment: Thanks for all your help - I eventually gave up on Fiddler and created my own .NET based test client, and after a lot of struggling and mucking around, I got this to work just fine by now.